# CSS - Apply a gradient that remains fixed as the div scrolls

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to web design, and I've been struggling with this effect for several hours now. I'd like to have a scrolling text box wherein there is a gradient over the text and that gradient stays fixed as you scroll up and down. The code I have now produces a scrolling div with a gradient, but that gradient is produced over the whole height of the text included in the div. I want the scope of the gradient to be limited to the div itself, if that makes sense.

A solution that seems to be almost there is to give the gradient div fixed position. However, when your mouse is over this fixed div, you cannot scroll through the (parent) div that's underneath it.

My apologies if this has been answered elsewhere. I hunted around but could have missed or misread something.

Anyhoo here is a jfiddle showing what is currently going on: http://jsfiddle.net/sP2e5/

Here is the actual html:

```
<div class="transcript" id="prisonerResponse">
        <p>i'm actually including an obnoxious amount of text 
           so you can see the scrolling effect: so much textso much 
            textso much 
            textso much textso much textso much 
            textso much textso much textso much textso 
            much textso much textso much textso much textso 
            much textso much textso much textso much 
            textso much textso much textso much 
            textso much textso much textso much t
            extso much textso much textso much t
            extso much textso much textso much 
            textso much textso much textso much 
            textso much textso much textso much text</p>
            <div class="transcriptGradient"> </div>

</div>
```

and here is the css:

```
 .transcript{
    overflow:scroll; 
    width:350px; 
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:20px;
    position:relative;
    }

.transcriptGradient{
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100% );
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); 
}
```

Comment: Does `background-position:fixed` solve your problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/S2G8H/1/

Comment: thanks a ton for your responses. i can't upvote people yet, but several responses were informative. mustafa's may be the only one that does exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `:before` selector in `div.transcript`, you don't need extra `div` to achieve this result. All you need is `position: fixed;` applied to `.transcript:before`.

The downside of these methods (put gradient above scrollable content) is in Firefox, you cannot scroll the content if your cursor is on the gradient. So put your attention on gradient height.

**HTML**

```
<div class="transcript" id="prisonerResponse">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. [...] </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.transcript {
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 350px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.transcript:before {
    content:"";
    width: 350px;
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: this works perfectly, thank you so much! i actually don't have any trouble scrolling with my cursor over the gradient, but maybe i misunderstood. 

i'll read up on the :before and :after pseudoelements.

Comment: It does make trouble on Firefox, but not in Chrome :D My mistake. I've edited my answer.

Comment: This only works if you have only one `.transcript` and no vertical scrolling in the whole screen (`body`). With `position:fixed` the element is removed from the flow of the document and will always be relative to the document, not the element, and also unaffected by scroll. Davis' solution supports multiple `.transcript` and a `document` with vertical scrolling.

Comment: If you add pointer-events: none, you should be able to scroll over the gradient as well

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care too much what the code looks like... here's a "ok" way to solve your issue, change the `.transcriptGradient` placement:

**[Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/S2G8H/1/)**